# Etherbase, Coinbase and Uncle

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs

what is the main difference between etherbase and coinbase? And what is the meaning of "uncle" in a transaction?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Coinbase and Etherbase are the same, which is your default address where mining reward is going/credited in.

Uncle is a block that in bitcoin would be considered an orphan because its not on the longest chain (it's an alternative block at the same height as your parent). In some content I heard people refer it as family tree Dad and you are correct chain where uncle is almost correct but not accepted one.